# How can I download data from s3 bucket using browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser, bucket

I want to download data from my S3 bucket. I got the URL from AWS console and tried to get data using the browser but It returns this error

"Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4."

How to fix It?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what you are wanting to do, so that we can provide a suitable answer? Are you wanting to download data just once, or is this a repeated process? Are you having difficulties downloading from the Amazon S3 management console? When you "got the URL from AWS console", where specifically did you obtain it? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information?

Comment: I want to save the URL of my resource in my favourite sites and download the data when I want, many times. I wanto to download the data using every browser, want to give access to anyone so that anybody can do it from his computer.I got the URL from S3 console by browsing my bucket at https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/codepipeline-us-west-2-62302200753

Comment: If an object is public in Amazon S3, then its URL would be: `BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/KEY` where `KEY` is the full name of the object, including its path.

Comment: thanks, I did it. But I cannot download the entire folder but only the object. Can you confirm me that there is not this feature in s3?

Comment: Correct. Amazon S3 can serve individual objects, but not folders. (In fact, folders do not actually existing in Amazon S3. Rather, the `Key` of an object includes its full path.) If you wish to copy a folder, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp --recursive` or `aws s3 sync` commands. It will loop through the folders, copying all files.